# Html.Action not work

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, view

i want to bring the partial view of question link list to my edit view. However, when i select the groupby value, it shows the error below. Please guide me.

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType4`2[SurveyTool.Models.SURV_Question_Ext_Model,SurveyTool.Models.SURV_Question_Model]]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[SurveyTool.Models.SURV_Question_Ext_Model]'.

Edit view:

```
@model IFXSurveyTool.Models.SURV_Main_Model

    <div class="question">

            <h2>Link</h2>

            @Html.Action("QuestionLink", "SURV_Main", new { Survey_ID = Model.Survey_ID })

        </div>
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult QuestionLink(int Survey_ID)
        {
            var query = from r in db.SURV_Question_Ext_Model
                        join s in db.SURV_Question_Model on r.Qext_Question_ID equals s.Question_ID
                        where s.Question_Survey_ID == Survey_ID
                        group new { r, s } by r.Qext_Language into grp
                        select grp.FirstOrDefault();

            return PartialView(query.ToList());
        }
```

QuestionLink view:

```
@model IEnumerable<SurveyTool.Models.SURV_Question_Ext_Model>

<br />
<table class="strip">

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td width="5%"></td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("QuestionLink", "Edit", "SURV_Answer", new { Language = item.Qext_Language }, null)
            </td>


        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change following line in Your PartialView code:

```
@model IEnumerable<SurveyTool.Models.SURV_Question_Ext_Model>
```

to:

```
@model List<SurveyTool.Models.SURV_Question_Ext_Model>
```

Or returning type in controller. Types needs match.

From comments:
there is also returned group of LINQ query, so it's anoumous Type, not the one You expecting.

Comment: I had change to List but still same. No luck.

Comment: there is also returned group of LINQ query, so it's anoumous Type, not the one You expecting. What YOu try to pass to Your view? is it collection of Keys from this group? or First group values?

Comment: var query = from r in db.SURV_Question_Ext_Model
                        join s in db.SURV_Question_Model on r.Qext_Question_ID equals s.Question_ID
                        where s.Question_Survey_ID == Survey_ID
                        group new { r, s } by r.Qext_Language into grp
                        select grp.FirstOrDefault();

Comment: select grp returns in this case Group which contains of Key object and collection of values. And whole query returns collection of grp items, so anonymous type given in exception,

Comment: I want join the the table and get the value from 2 tables. Which is data from SURV_Question_Ext_Model and SURV_Question_Model.

Answer (score 0):

You have little error. Try this:

```
@model IEnumerable<SurveyTool.Models.SURV_Question_Ext_Model>

<br />
<table class="strip">

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td width="5%"></td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "QuestionLink", "SURV_Answer", new { Language = item.Qext_Language }, null)
            </td>

    </tr>
}
```

Comment: I don't see any different.

Comment: maybe this is the reason : @Html.ActionLink("QuestionLink", "Edit", "SURV_Answer", new { Language = item.Qext_Language }, null) -> @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "QuestionLink", "SURV_Answer", new { Language = item.Qext_Language }, null)